# Is there a way to "Select * -Unique" with unique nested objects, without changing the objects?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the following:

```
$x = @()

$x += [pscustomobject]@{
    a=1
    b=2
    c=[pscustomobject]@{
        a=1
        b=2
    }
}

$x += [pscustomobject]@{
    a=1
    b=2
    c=[pscustomobject]@{
        a=3
        b=4
    }
}

$x | Select * -Unique
```

My desired behaviour would be to return both objects inside `$x`, since `$x.c` contains unique items. I cannot simply run `$x.c | Select * -Unique` because I want to store and associate the entire object.

The above code, regardless of the exact objects, simply returns the first object.

Is there a way to produce my desired behaviour without just flattening all my objects?

---

Potential very messy solution using invoke-expression:

```
$a = $x | gm | ? {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' -and $_.Definition -like '*object*'} | select -ExpandProperty Name
$y = @()
$a | %{
    $p = $_
    $x.$p | gm | ? {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | select -ExpandProperty Name | % { $y += "{`$_.$p.$_}" }
}

$y = ($y | convertto-json -Compress) -replace '\[' -replace '\]' -replace '\"'

iex -command ('$x | Sort (iex $y) -Unique |Select *')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this armed with the knowledge that sort-object can distinguish properties using scriptblocks. I essentially just pull all the properties I'm interested in, create the script block, and add that to an array.

```
$itemsToExpand = $x | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' -and $_.Definition -like '*object*'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$scriptBlockArray = @()
$itemsToExpand | ForEach-Object{
    $current = $_
    $x.$current | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object { 
      $scriptBlockArray += [Scriptblock]::Create("`$_.$current.$_")
    }
}

$x | Sort-Object $scriptBlockArray -Unique
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distinguish the properties of `c`, use `Sort-Object` first:

```
$x |Sort {$_.c.a},{$_.c.b} -Unique |Select *
```

Comment: Very useful but `c` is not a static value. I might be able to figure out some way to use this, however. It seems possible.

Comment: Okay well this is one of the more convoluted things I've done, but maybe you have a better idea how to achieve this... I am editing my question with a potential solution.

Comment: I'm parsing JSON and don't really want to iex any random property name that comes through. I might eventually end up having to process mr bobby table's file.